# Android app crashing on device using Google Map

Tags: android

I am incorporating a map on device and it causes the app crash on device. It works fine on emulator(however, it doesnt have Google Play Services installed and thats ossibly why it doesnt crash) it has to do something with google play services. My build.gradle is below:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jorc.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' }
```

When I use the same build process for the map from Android Studio templates it works fine on the device. I assume I am not doing the setup right.

The MapActivity.java is also below:

```
package com.jorc.fleetmanamgement;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.jorc.fleetmanagement.R;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

The map is embedded in this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.jorc.fleetmanagement.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/maptext"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@id/maptext"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The build gradle for project is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gsm:google-services:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and app build gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jorc.fleetmanagement"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

The logcat is below:

```
12-05 00:50:36.949 5005-5005/com.jorc.fleetmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jorc.fleetmanagement, PID: 5005
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jorc.fleetmanagement/com.jorc.fleetmanagement.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.jorc.fleetmanagement.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ad.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.b(SourceFile:179)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(SourceFile:100)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzt(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzzh(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1129)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2283)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutIn
12-05 00:51:21.310 5005-5005/com.jorc.fleetmanagement I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5005 SIG: 9
```

Comment: And the crash would be? Please, post your logcat

Comment: Use `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: can you try `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CAUSE

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>` is in the `<application>` element of AndroidManifest.xml

### Solution

Get an API key from google.

### Previous assumptions

You also need to set your dependencies in the other gradle file(the project one)

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:x.x.x'
```

Look for the version yourself.

Had the same issue once. I'm not very fond of gradle, but it is needed.

Resolved your issue?

### Update 1

You also need to add apply plugin on top of your gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### Update 2

My gradle for google services

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
}
```

Comment: There is another classpath there, is this added to that or this replaces that one?

Comment: got this error Error:Could not find com.google.gsm:google-services:1.5.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.jar
Required by:

Comment: plus that android map template doesnt have any of this?

Comment: you have two gradle files (one on project level, one on module level) should be straight forward. The apply plugin to your build.gradle the other add to depencies in the other

Comment: Got error message Error:Could not find com.google.gsm:google-services:1.5.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.jar
Required by:

Comment: Still gives this error         Error:Could not find com.google.gsm:google-services:1.5.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gsm/google-services/1.5.0/google-services-1.5.0.jar

Comment: also Error:(3, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
<a href="openFile:D:\Amir\Geoapps_windows\Android\FleetManagement2\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: None of these you mentioned is in the google map template included in the Android Studio. I think it has to do with the libraries which possibly wasnt included.

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong in the mapactivity as I am not injecting the view properly.

Comment: Why is setcontentview commented and TRy to debug and look if your mapfragment isnt null

Comment: Your api key isnt filled in : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml => you should request one

Comment: That shouldnt be the problem.

Comment: I moved this under a new button=m and get this error 12-05 02:19:46.464 1939-1939/com.jorc.fleetmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                              Process: com.jorc.fleetmanagement, PID: 1939
          android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.jorc.fleetmanagement/com.jorc.fleetmanamgement.MapsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Somehow I cant work out a way to let java know the class in the mainactivity folder

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my Android Manifest was missing the API key for google map